# Can someone explain source (versioning) control to me?

Tags: version-control

I've never worked on a professional project with a team, as I'm still in high school. As a consequence, I've never been exposed to this whole "versioning" and "source control" thing. Are they the same? How exactly does a program that manages code manage code? I've heard you have to check out code (copy the existing code?) and merge it back in (what happens if someone changes code that you didn't change and you change something else and merge it in? Surely, his code is not replaced by your older version.) And, finally, what is the best/easiest example of this type of software?

Comment: I believe [this article](http://betterexplained.com/articles/a-visual-guide-to-version-control/) explains the answers to most of your questions.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> I've heard you have to check out code
>   (copy the existing code?) and merge it
>   back in (what happens if someone
>   changes code that you didn't change
>   and you change something else and
>   merge it in? Surely, his code is not
>   replaced by your older version.)

That is precisely the reason for version control. It wouldn't really be a very useful tool if all it did was blindly overwrite people's code, would it? ;)

Source control tools maintain a repository with the entire history of the codebase. Every change is checked in as a delta, saving *just what has changed*. That means that if you and I both check out version A, and I then edit file B, and you edit file C, and we both check in, the source control software will compare the differences and where no conflicts exist (as in this case), just apply both changes, and if conflicts occur (if we both changed the same lines of code), it rejects the attempted check-in and tells you which two versions of the file had conflicting changes, and asks you to merge them manually. (usually it is also able to highlight the changes so you can see visually what has been changed in each version).
So it never overwrites changes.

Other tasks it'll do for you is:

- Tag specific versions or milestones
  so you can easily find them again
  later (this is the version where we
  finally fixed annoying bug #2524,
  this is beta 1, and so on
- Branch the repository into two,
  allowing changes that may go "out of
  sync" temporarliy, or even stay
  separate products forever (think of
  PHP simultaneously maintaining their
  PHP4 branch, while also working on
  PHP5. At some point they simly
  branched their codebase so while
  they started out identical, they can
  now apply patches to one without
  affecting the other). Of course it
  can also attempt to merge these
  branches back together (you may
  create a branch for each major
  feature in your product, perhaps, so
  they can be developed in isolation
  without being affected by the
  gradual changes happening to the
  rest of the code, and then when the
  feature is done, merge its branch
  back into the main repository)

There are two basic kinds of source control tools, the centralized ones and the distributed ones. Distributed are the *big new thing*, while centralized has been with us for decades. In brief, centralized version control simply means that there is one master repository server, where all branches and the change history for each are stored. This server is responsible for merging checkins and all that. So every time a developer checks code out or commits it to the repository, this is the server he syncs up against.
Distributed ones simply ditch the "main server" aspect of this. Instead, every time you check out your code, you create a new repository locally on your own machine, at the path you check out the code to. Then you can work against this local repository, which does all the same things, tracking change history, merging changes and so on, and once you're ready, you can merge your repository into, well, any other repository. Typically, you'll probably want to merge it into some kind of "main" repo where all the code gets glued together, but you can also merge it into your codeveloper's local repo, if perhaps he needs that feature you've been working on, but it's not yet stable enough to go into the main repo. So it gives you a lot more flexibility, and allows you to maintain a change history of your local work, without risking breaking the build at the master repository (in a centralized setup, what happens if you check in something that doesn't compile? The entire team is screwed until it's fixed. And if you *don't* check it in, you lose the benefits of version control, preventing you from reverting to a previous version if you find out you've been introducing new bugs)

> And, finally, what is the
>   best/easiest example of this type of
>   software?

Hm, the most popular is easily SVN, which an old-fashioned centralized system, but it's a bit of a pain to set up imo. Requires special software on the server.
I personally am quite fond of [Bazaar](http://bazaar-vcs.org/), which is distributed, and a server repository only requires FTP access and nothing else on the server.

Comment: Now this is thorough. Thanks a big ginormous bunch!

Comment: ftp access is not secure comms though...  not a good thing for people who want security/privacy...

Comment: SVN can also function as svn+ssh, so no need for the webdav or svn server extensions.

Comment: Tim: Fair enough, it works with SFTP as well, my point was simply that you don't need anything bazaar-specific installed on the server. Just access to the file system.
David: svn+ssh requires svnserve installed though, doesn't it? Otherwise I don't see how it can function as centralized vers.control

Comment: Only if we had VisualBZR for Visual Studio... 8->

Comment: I'd upvote if he had included a part on Git.

Answer (score 11):

Eric Sink has written a nice [Source Control HOWTO](http://www.ericsink.com/scm/source_control.html).

Disclaimer: Eric Sink is a principal of SourceGear which develops and sells several source control-related tools (including SourceGear Vault).  However, the [Source Control HOWTO](http://www.ericsink.com/scm/source_control.html) is a pretty neutral, balanced writeup.

Answer (score 5):

Version control systems aren't just for large teams! The individual developer working on a hobby project has much to gain from versioning their code.

Most version control systems are centered around the concept of a *repository*, which is managed by the system and never touched directly. When you want to edit a file, you copy it from the repository, make your changes, then send it back. The version control system identifies the differences between your new version and the old version, then stores your new version in the repository. But, in case you screwed up, the older versions, going all the way back to the beginning, are always retrievable.

Most version control systems are smart enough to merge changes from multiple developers on the same file, as long as the changes don't affect the same part of the file. Merge conflict can occur and cause headaches, however.

To get started, I recommend you install something simple and free like [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) and go through their very detailed [book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) which has examples and explanations of the various features, most of which work comparably in other version control systems.

Comment: I bullied a good friend of mine into using SVN for his small projects and code.  He's since become a SVN junkie and is slowly moving all of his code library ( snippets and ideas) into SVN.  Its made him a lot happier and productive.

Answer (score 5):

All version control systems are basically the same.. None are any more difficult to use than the other.. `svn commit somefile` is as difficult as `git commit somefile`.. They just all work a bit differently.

The only reason I started using git is because of [github](http://github.com). Previous to that the only reason I used SVN over darcs (which has a really nice command-line interface) was because I found a good, free SVN server.

Currently I would recommend git. Not because it's better, or because some other VCS is worse, but because there are lots of really good guides, and lots of really good projects using/based-on it.

Some resources you may find useful:

- [GitHub](http://github.com/) - what convinced me to start using git. It has a very active community, and is very helpful (when you create a new repository, it gives you the commands to push your code to it, for example). They have a good [guides](http://github.com/guides/home) section too.
- A free [screencast about using GitHub](http://www.pragprog.com/screencasts/v-scgithub/insider-guide-to-github) - explains lots of the sites features, and most of the useful basics
- [Gitorious](http://gitorious.com/) - another good git hosting site, for open-source projects (the site itself is open-source too). Not quite as nice to use as GitHub I would say, but a very good alternative.
- [repo.or.cz](http://repo.or.cz/) - the first git hosting sites. Pretty archaic looking compared to GitHub/Gitorious, but it works, and hosts
- [PeepCode's Git episode](http://peepcode.com/products/git) - $9, but is regarded very highly. Covers pretty much everything you'd need to know.
- [GitCasts](http://www.gitcasts.com/) - a series of good screencasts. Start with the first one ("Setup, Initialization and Cloning"), and it should cover most useful things.
- [GitMagic](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~blynn/gitmagic/) - extremely useful, especially for slightly more advanced things (It has answered a lot of my "How do I.." questions, like how to create an empty branch). Comprehensive guide (goes from basic stuff to git's internals)
- [Git for beginners: The definitive practical guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide) - a question on stackoverflow - not exactly comprehensive yet, but it's getting there..

All that said, it's irrelevant what version control system you choose, really..

I found [darcs](http://darcs.net) really easy to use (both it's CLI, and understanding how `darcs get` worked to move "patches" between repositories. The ["GettingStarted" darcs.net wiki page](http://wiki.darcs.net/DarcsWiki/GettingStarted) was about all I needed to get started. The only problem I had was I couldn't find any hosts for darcs projects...

SVN is easy to use, but it's centralised architecture didn't really fit how I used it, and things like branching (which is trivial in git) is difficult. Almost every action requires communicating with a central server, and I didn't want to run a local SVN server. It also basically doesn't work offline, on a laptop for example.

I started out learning SVN, mainly thanks to ["introduction to Subversion screencast"](http://blog.clickablebliss.com/2006/04/26/introduction-to-subversion-screencast/). Then when I discovered github I used `git svn` to import my main SVN repository into git

In short: Find a good tutorial or guide for some version control system, and version all those random projects and snippets you have. It'll seem a bit pointless until you accidently make some stupid change and save/close your script, or accidently delete something.. I pretty much use VCS as "super-undo" (and for code synchronisation between computers)

Answer (score 3):

Versioning and Source Control are the same.  Well, mostly.  Versioning is what Source Control does.  It allows you to have multiple versions of a file.  Think of it like Wikipedia's revision history.  You can go back, see what was done, compare changes, and roll back to previous code.

The program normally uses some proprietary engine to keep tabs on these files (since they're just text, it normally isn't tough), and it keeps track of changes made each time the file is checked back in.

If you try to merge a file back in that's been changed, most Source control systems will show you a diff of the files and you can choose to merge it manually or automatically (depending on how powerful your Source control system is).

The easiest example is to [download Subversion onto your USB drive](http://dotnet.org.za/trumpi/archive/2006/12/13/Subversion-on-a-stick.aspx), and install [Tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some answers to your questions:

Source control is a place where everyone shares their code. When you want to make a change, you "check out" the code and modify it. While you have it checked out, no one else can make changes to it (thus preventing you from modifying an older version of the file). When you are done, you check the file back into the source control, creating a new version (this is the versioning portion of source control). At any point in time, you can resynchronize your local copy of the code base with the latest versions of all the files, keeping you up to date.

Some software that does this uses a change system. That means that there is a single copy of the file which, whenever it gets checked in, is saved as a sequence of changes to that file. Other systems store multiple copies of the file, and attach version information to the file.

If you were to change an older version of the file, and then discover that you worked off an old version (the source control program should notify you when you try to check in your code), then you would have to merge your changes with the newer version. Some source control tools come with a built in merge tool.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the second question you posted:

SVN requires a centralized repository while Git is decentralized but the majority of the people I know who use it rely on github.  Also Git is used for the main trunk of the linux kernel source code so its been optimized a bit more for very large code bases.  Also Git seems to have a better handle on branch merging then pre-svn 1.5.x code.

Answer (score 0):

Versioning doesn't need to be a complicated setup nor something that is only suitable for working in a team environment and it isn't only for coding projects. Anything can go into version control. It's simply a matter of not wanting to lose *anything*. I version control virtually every file i edit, including everything in my home/ and lots of config files in etc/ and elsewhere and i version everything i do for work (in addition to the versioning provided for the projects). It's such a part of what i do, i think it should be provided by the filesystem.

I recommend starting simple and practice with RCS. Although RCS sucks for teams, it is just fine for managing local user files with only a single author. Don't concern yourself with merges and branches just yet. Learn to think of saving a file as meaning saving a version. Once you're comfortable with RCS and accept the benefit of retaining changes, you can move up to learning SVN or Git or any other *real* system which are far more robust and better suited for team environments.

Answer (score 0):

Also take a look at the [Streamed Lines paper](http://www.cmcrossroads.com/bradapp/acme/branching/) it describes a number of best practices and version control anti-patterns, I'd also second the reference to [Erik Sinks articles](http://www.ericsink.com/scm/source_control.html) mentioned by Michael Burr